# How do I fix this? Boxplot is vertical by default. The output for this boxplot in my Jupyter notebook is horizontal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn, boxplot

The output of my box plot does not change from horizontal to vertical even after setting the orient to be vertical, it remains horizontal. How can I fix this?

```
import seaborn as sns
#sns.set()
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(10,10)

data_BM = pd.read_csv('bigmart_data.csv')

data_BM = data_BM.dropna(how="any")

data_BM["Visibility_Scaled"] = data_BM["Item_Visibility"] * 100

data_BM.head()

sns.boxplot(data_BM['Item_Outlet_Sales'], orient='v')
```

Comment: Re-write this example to include one of seaborn’s built-in datasets. Right now, this example only runs on your machine and no one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the latest seaborn version. You'll need to explicitly use the `x=` keyword as in   `sns.boxplot(x=data_BM['Item_Outlet_Sales'])` or the `data=` keyword to plot multiple columns: `sns.boxplot(data=df[['col1', 'col2']], orient='v')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
sns.boxplot(y = data_BM['Item_Outlet_Sales'])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.